# PHP multiple file upload not Fatal error Maximum execution timeout

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple images to multiple directories. What I'm really doing here is form will allow users to upload two images, it will rename both the images with the same name to two directories and log it to the database. But my below code doesn't show any error while processing and after 180 seconds I'm getting an error for exceeding maximum execution time at line 11 (`while (file_exists($target_full)) {`). Images are 100% taken but not found on the server and also it is not being logged in the database.

I'm doing it in the simplest way. I think the problem occurs at the renaming of images from file exist. Could someone help me fix this?

**function.php**

```
<?php

$target_full = "/test/av-full/";
$target_tp   = "/test/av-tp/";
$tmp         = explode(".", $_FILES["photo_full"]["name"]);
$photo_full  = time() . '_' . rand(100, 999) . '.' . end($tmp);
$photo_tp    = "$photo_full";
$target_full = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/av-full/");
$target_tp   = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/av-tp/");

while (file_exists($target_full)) {
    $tmp         = explode(".", $_FILES["photo_full"]["name"]);
    $photo_full  = time() . '_' . rand(100, 999) . '.' . end($tmp);
    $target_full = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/av-full/");
}
while (file_exists($target_tp)) {
    $photo_tp  = "$photo_full";
    $target_tp = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/av-tp/");
}

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die("MySQL Login problem!");
mysqli_select_db($con, "database") or die("Could not connect to database!");


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo_full']['tmp_name'], $target_full)) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo_tp']['tmp_name'], $target_tp)) {

        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table (photo_full,photo_tp)
            VALUES ('$photo_full','$photo_tp')");

    } else {
        echo "photo 340px error.";
    }
    echo "The file <b>" . basename($_FILES['photo_full']['name']) . "</b> & <b>" . basename($_FILES['photo_tp']['name']) . "</b> has been uploaded, and renamed to <b>$photo_tp</b>. This is for your information.";
} else {
    echo "error occured";
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="function.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <label>upload image to database</label><br>
        <br>
        <label>full size image :</label> <input name="size" type="hidden" value="350000"> <input name="photo[]" type="file"><br>
        <br>
        <label>340px size image :</label> <input name="size" type="hidden" value="350000"> <input name="photo[]" type="file"><br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" type="submit" value="Add Member">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To answer your question "Is there anything I'm missing in my codes?": Sure, there might be. Little more we can say, since we do not know what you expect to happen.

Comment: @RaxShah I don't think so it is time problem because file upload was done within 10 seconds.

Comment: Then most likely one of your loops is an endless loop. Start logging progress markers.

Comment: @arkascha I explained at the top that I'm trying to upload two images to two directories.

Comment: Sure. So? Don't get me wrong, I am just trying to point out that you made a huge mistake: you just dump your code here and ask: why doesn't this work? Note that such questions are _clearly_ considered off-topic here. You are meant to be much more precise and to point out what you have already done to fix the issue yourself.

Comment: `while (file_exists(...))` this is permanent true condition. Since file exists in every iteration and you get an infinite loop

Comment: @arkascha edited the question.

Comment: Are the files uploaded? Are they stored? Are the entries being made in the database? Did you try adding progress markers into a log file / into the output? _What did you yourself do to find out what the issue is_?

Comment: @arkascha question edited!

Comment: @JessieJackson Now what will I have to do to fix infinite loop here?

Comment: The first loop is endless , since you check if the _folder_ exists. Without deleting that folder the loop certainly will continue forever. Why a `while` loop?

Comment: @arkascha So, what will  I do to rename both the images? I should first find the images at the server with file_exists right?

Comment: The while is to find an available name... but you forgot to concatenante the newly generated name : `while (file_exists($target_full.$photo_full)) {`

Comment: Since you based to final file name on the current time as far as I understand you are guaranteed that the files do _not_ yet exist. So you do not have to check that.

Comment: That might be, but it makes no sense. The time prefix guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: @arkascha Is there any other method to check if the file exist without `while`, maybe an `if` statement?

Comment: One last time: _you do not have to check that, it is impossible that such file exists_. (Ok, unless you specifically created such file manually, but I think we can rule that out...)

Comment: @arkascha then how will I find the uploaded images to rename?

Comment: `$_FILES['photo_full']['tmp_name']` this is the temporary name where the http server has temporarily placed the images for you. You already know that. You then move the file using `move_uploaded_file()` to the final location. That location is the name you created based on the time stamp. That final location (path) is what you enter into your database.

Comment: Oh, and a warning: you should _not_ use part of the file name specified by the client side. You are not interested in that and it may open security holes like sql injection attacks, since you use the final file name as part of your database queries. Stick with just the time based prefix and maybe some id for the file name.